# DomainLabelEmpty (Domain label is empty) encountered with 'semantic-search-v2.aws.magna.china.'

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

I can create A record in Route53:
[image]

But when I use cdk code to do the same thing. It failed.
This is the Code:

```
    // ALB names are limited to 32 characters...workaround
    let lbNameLength = 28 
    let truncatedServiceName = props.serviceName.substring(0, lbNameLength)

    // Creating an internet facing ALB
    const loadBalancer = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, "alb", {
      vpc: props.cluster.vpc,
      vpcSubnets: {
        subnets: props.cluster.vpc.privateSubnets
      },
      loadBalancerName: `${truncatedServiceName}-lb`,
      idleTimeout: Duration.seconds(3600)
    });

    // Allowing incoming connections 
    loadBalancer.connections.allowFromAnyIpv4(ec2.Port.tcp(props.lbPort), "Allow inbound HTTP");

    // Creating a listener and listen to incoming requests
    const listener = loadBalancer.addListener("listener", {
      port: props.lbPort,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP
    });

    // Creating a target group that points to the application container (e.g. port 8080)
    listener.addTargets("targets", {
      port: props.containerPort,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      targets: [service],
      healthCheck: {
        path: '/health'
      }
    });

    const dnsParams= dnsParameters(this, id)

    const magnaHostedZone = route53.HostedZone.fromHostedZoneAttributes(this, 'hostedZone', {
      hostedZoneId: dnsParams.hostedZoneId,
      zoneName: dnsParams.zoneName
    })

    // Using alias because load balancer is an AWS resource
    new route53.ARecord(this, 'aRecord', {
      zone: magnaHostedZone,
      target: route53.AddressRecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.LoadBalancerTarget(loadBalancer)),
      recordName: "semantic-search-v2"
    });
```

When I run this typescript cdk code, it occurs this error:

```
DomainLabelEmpty (Domain label is empty) encountered with 'semantic-search-v2.aws.magna.china.' (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: 9f643150-262c-43fc-87ff-800dca172171; Proxy: null)
```

I don't know what does 'DomainLabelEmpty' mean.

BTW, all the subnets of my account are private and cannot access the public network.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending the r53 hosted zone name to the `recordName` attribute of ARecord.